# Eslint error: 'no-unused-vars' in typescript interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have found this issue over and over in Typescript but haven't been able to find a solution other than disabling the rule for the selected code.

Every time I declare a function with parameters in a **Typescript Interface** I get the `no-unused-vars` error on the parameter, see example below.

```js
interface Template {
    template: Template;
    setTemplate: (template: Template) => void;
}
```

In this case, the `setTemplate()` function would throw an Eslint warning: `'template' is defined but never used: Eslint no-unused-vars`

Does anyone know the Eslint rule or config required to avoid this, tired of adding `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars`.

Comment: How is ESLint set up for your codebase?

Comment: It is quite a large file didn't want to post the whole thing but the relevant rule in my eslint config is:   no-unused-vars: - warn

Comment: We don't want that either! Give a [mre]. Have you read e.g. https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/HEAD/docs/getting-started/linting/FAQ.md#i-am-using-a-rule-from-eslint-core-and-it-doesnt-work-correctly-with-typescript-code?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, that's correct. The ESLint rule is broken for TS. There is a separate TS rules. Let me find it.

Comment: Got it. Check the dupe. You need @typescript-eslint and then disable the regular `no-unused-vars`, use the `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`

Comment: Will have a look now, I am using the '@typescript-eslint' in my eslint config

Comment: Disabling the rule seems to have solved it, thanks!

Comment: Yes. For whatever reason the plain ESLint rule `no-unused-vars` just doesn't work. AFAIK, you **have to** disable it. I think it's just that one, anything else is compatible with TS.